# Web statistics using PHP (laravel)/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a login/logout application which I created using Laravel 4. I need to make a web statistics so whenever the user login it will show me a line graph with the amount of users within a day.

Below is my login method from which I save data in the database whenever a user login.

```
 public function postLogin() {

    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array('email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required');
    $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($v);
    } else {
        $credentials = array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $id = Auth::user()->id;
            $auditor = new Auditor();
            $auditor->user_id = $id;
            $auditor->operation = 'login';
            $auditor->save();
            return Redirect::to('admin');
        } else {
            return View::make('home.login', array('message' => 'Wrong username/password!'));
        }
    }
}
```

I have a controller where I group my data from database. I know it is not correct but I don't know how to continue to create the graph.

```
public function graph() {
    $auditor = new Auditor();
    $auditor = array();
    //get data from database
    $sql = "SELECT  DATE('auditor'.'created') AS date" . "COUNT('auditor'.'auditor_id') AS 'count'". "FROM 'auditor'".
    "WHERE auditor .created BETWEEN 2015-09-01 00:00:00 AND 2015-09-31 23:59:59". "GROUP BY date"."ORDER BY date";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        }
    }
```

Please can you help me how to draw a graph and is it possible to display data in the graph after grouped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second [phpChart](http://phpchart.com/). Used it in the past for an online report task. Very easy to create charts quickly.

Here's the solution to your scenario using phpChart based on their [online example -- Axis Labels Rotated Text 2:](http://phpchart.com/phpChart/examples/axis_labels_rotated_text_2.php)

```
    <?php 
$line = array(array('user', 12), array('admin', 3), array('user2', 1), array('user3', 1));

$pc = new C_PhpChartX(array($line),'user_chart');
$pc->add_plugins(array('canvasTextRenderer'));
//set series
$pc->add_series(array('renderer'=>'plugin::BarRenderer'));
//set axes
$pc->set_axes(array(
    'xaxis'  => array(
        'renderer'=>'plugin::CategoryAxisRenderer',
        'tickRenderer'=>'plugin::CanvasAxisTickRenderer'),
    'yaxis'  => array(
        'autoscale'=>true,
        'tickRenderer'=>'plugin::CanvasAxisTickRenderer')
));

$pc->draw(800,500);
?>
```

**Result:**
[image]

Here's a great intro on Codeproject I found: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/604542/Creating-Interactive-HTML5-Graphs-in-PHP

Laravel doesn't provides any charting library out of the box. You need to find a third party library written in PHP to generate charts from your Laravel app.

Some free library for charting are:

- [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) - A PHP class to build charts. Sample chart shown below:[image]
- [phpCHART - Make HTML5 Charts in PHP](http://phpchart.com/). Sample chart shown below:[image]

I strongly encourage you to search for [php charting library](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20chart) here in StackOverflow to see the opinion from other experienced users.

When choosing a particular library add it to you composer.json file as any other dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the data from PHP you can use some javascript charting tool like Chart.js.

Comment: I did use chart.js and it works i just have problems to display data from database. Thank you